# Script that prints specific lines of a file

Tags: linux, shell, file

I have some trouble with this script that prints content of a file from a given line number to the next line number specified. If START is greater than END (example `./script file 10 7`), I need to print the lines from START argument back to END argument (so basically line 10, then line 9 8 7).

```
#!/bin/sh

START=$1
END=$2
FILENAME=$3

ERROR="[PINCH ERROR]"
if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
    echo "$ERROR Need three arguments: Filename Start-line End-line"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$FILENAME" ]; then
    echo -e "$ERROR File does not exist. \n\t$FILENAME"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$START" -gt "$END" ]; then
    echo -e "$END $START"
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$START" -lt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$ERROR Start line is less than 0."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$END" -lt 0 ]; then
    echo -e "$ERROR End line is less than 0."
    exit 1
fi

NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < "$FILENAME")

ENDDIFF=$(( NUMOFLINES - END ))

if [ "$START" -lt "$ENDDIFF" ]; then
    < "$FILENAME" head -n $END | tail -n +$START
else
    < "$FILENAME" tail -n +$START | head -n $(( END-START+1 ))
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this linux, you probably have [tac(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) available, which makes it easy:

```
if [ "$START" -le "$END" ]; then
   # Normal output
   sed -n "${START},${END}p; ${END}q" "$FILENAME"
else
    # Reverse output
    sed -n "${END},${START}p; ${START}q" "$FILENAME" | tac
fi
```